# Unable to upload ( image + user data ) from react to node.js backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image-upload, react-forms

When i click the register button then the REGISTER_USER function is called and then it creates a form obj with all the data and post it to the backend . i don't know why it is giving 500 error , cors error even tough i added cors in my app.js (node.js file)
Please help me with this issue ! Thanks in advance ...

**Error**

[image]

**This is my backend Code**
This implementsthe upload file and the user data to the data base

```
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./assets/images/Customers",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.originalname.split(".")[0] +
        "-" +
        Date.now() +
        "." +
        file.originalname.split(".")[1]
    );
  },
});

const upload_image = multer({
  storage: imageStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10000000,
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/)) {
      return cb(new Error("Only Png / Jpg format is accepted"));
    }
    cb(undefined, true);
  },
});
router.post("/create-user", upload_image.single("image") , async (req, res) => {
  try{
      console.log(req.body)
      console.log(req.file.filename)
      let isPresent = await User.findOne({Name : req.body.Email.toLowerCase()})
      if(isPresent !== null){
          return res.status(400).json({ success : false , message : "Customer already present in the data base!"})
      }else{
          const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
          const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.Password , salt)
          let data = {...req.body , Name : req.body.Name.toLowerCase() , Password : hashedPassword , Email : req.body.Email.toLowerCase() , ProfilePic : req.file.filename};
          console.log(data)
          let Created_Customer = await User.create(data)
          return res.status(200).json({success : true , message : "Successfully created the customer!" , Customer : Created_Customer});
      }
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(500).json({success : false , message : err});
    }
});
```

**This is my  FrontEnd Form Code**

*Function that post the data*

```
const [adminData , setAdminData]  = useState({
      Name : "" ,
      Email : "",
      Password : "",
      Role : "admin",
      file : ""
    })
    const REGISTER_USER = async (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("Name" , adminData.Name)
      formData.append("Email" , adminData.Email)
      formData.append("Role" , adminData.Role)
      formData.append("Password" , adminData.Password)
      formData.append("image" , adminData.file)
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/create-user" , {
        method : "POST",
        body : formData
      })
      console.log(res)
    }
```

*form*

```
<form onSubmit={REGISTER_USER}> 
     
        <div>
          <span>Name</span>
          <span>
            <input type="text"  name ="Name" value ={adminData.Name} onChange={(e) => setAdminData({...adminData , [e.target.name] : e.target.value})}/>
            <PersonOutlineRoundedIcon/>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>Email</span>
          <span>
            <input type="text"  name ="Email" value ={adminData.Email} onChange={(e) => setAdminData({...adminData , [e.target.name] : e.target.value})}/>
            <PersonOutlineRoundedIcon/>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div >
          <span>Password</span>
          <span >
            <input type="password"  name ="Password" value ={adminData.Password} onChange={(e) => setAdminData({...adminData , [e.target.name] : e.target.value})}/>
            <VisibilityOutlinedIcon />
          </span>
        </div>
        <span>
            <input type="file" name ="file" value ={adminData.file} onChange={(e) => setAdminData({...adminData , [e.target.name] : e.target.value})}/>
        </span>
        <button type="submit">
          <span>Register</span> 
          <ArrowForwardOutlinedIcon/>
        </button>
      </form>
```

**Data is recieved in this format at the backend**
[image]

Comment: Hi, @Znoy I think it's a CORS error did you handle CORS  in your backend?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to upload images and other fields on different route handlers, so that if the user registration is successful then upload pictures, separate the handlers in the backend, and attach the other data in the front as stringed JSON while the image as multipart form data, with {new formData} Api, and attach it only when user reg is successful, that way they images wont be uploaded if user reg isn't successful, let the image req be a patch req with the user Id